# Parametrization of boundary of manifold with corner

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

The text I am using is Lee's Introduction to smooth manifold. The definition for manifold with corner is roughly as the following:

> $M$ is a topological $n$-manifold with boundary. A chart with corners for $M$ is a pair $(U,\varphi)$, where $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism to an open subset of $\overline{\mathbb{R}_+^n}$. $$\overline{\mathbb{R}_+^n}=\{(x_1,\cdots, x_n)\in \mathbb{R}^n:x_1,\cdots, x_n\geq 0\}$$

And $\partial M$ is defined as points $p$ such that $\varphi(p)\in\partial \overline{\mathbb{R}^n_+}$.

In the text, it says that $\partial M$ is not a manifold with corners, and for the computation of integral on $\partial M$, usually the technique is parametrization of $\partial M$.
But how can we parametrize $\partial M$ if $M$ does not have smooth structure? When we define a map $F$ from $D\subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ to $\partial M$, how do we define the smoothness of $F$ in this case?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a little farther down the same page, I explained that the boundary is a union of subsets that are manifolds with corners, and then on page 418, I explained that you integrate over the boundary by parametrizing each of those subsets and adding up the resulting integrals.

Comment: @JackLee Hi Jack, thanks for comment. The only thing I am not sure is globally the boundary is union of manifold with corners. Is the following the correct way to understand: locally, the boundary of manifold with corners $M$ is union of manifold with corners, and since the form $\omega$ is compactly supported, it can be covered by finitely many charts. We do make these charts disjoint and parametrize each chart?

Comment: One way to see that the boundary is a union of manifolds with corners is to let $A$ denote the set of boundary points minus corner points (which is a manifold without boundary), and then note that the closure of each connected component of $A$ is a manifold with corners, as can be verified in local charts.

Comment: To compute the integral, you can parametrize each of those boundary manifolds with corners. But the images of the parametrizations will not in general be disjoint, because they'll intersect along the corners. However, the intersection will have measure zero, so counting it twice in the integral will not affect the value of the integral.